# How to open display and brightness settings through your app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to open the display and brightness part of the settings app (to change the theme or appearance) through my own app.
 I know about url schemes but don't want to use it as I've seen that apps are getting rejected when using that.
I also know about people using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`, but can't figure out how to open the specific display and brightness tab.
 Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Short answer is there isn't such a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust brightness inside your app

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

Using a slider you can change the brightness accordingly

```
@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        
    UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(slider.value)
        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it because Apple doesn't allow developers to do so. They just told you when you tried to use UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString the first time.